# Laravel - Collection, add up unique value appears in two columns

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have the following PHP code:

```
$data = [
  [
    'home' => 'Red',
    'away' => 'Blue'
  ],
  [
    'home' => 'Orange',
    'away' => 'Blue'
  ],
  [
    'home' => 'Cyan',
    'away' => 'Blue'
  ],
  [
    'home' => 'Blue',
    'away' => 'Orange'
  ],
];

$games = collect($data);
```

How would I use Laravel's collections (or Eloquent) to create an array where it would output the number of times by count a unique value was in either column.

So for this, the results would be like:

```
$results = [
 [
   'Blue': 4,
   'Orange': 2,
   'Red': 1,
   'Cyan': 1
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need `flatten()` method  a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension, then you need `countBy()` method counts the occurrences of values in the collection.

```php
$data = [
    [
        'home' => 'Red',
        'away' => 'Blue',
    ],
    [
        'home' => 'Orange',
        'away' => 'Blue',
    ],
    [
        'home' => 'Cyan',
        'away' => 'Blue',
    ],
    [
        'home' => 'Blue',
        'away' => 'Orange',
    ],
];

$games = collect($data)
    ->flatten()
    ->countBy()
    ->all();
```

---

#### Update

`countBy()` method available from Laravel version `5.8`. If your Laravel `< 5.8`, you can try this :

```php
$games = collect($data)
    ->flatten()
    ->groupBy(function ($value) {
        return $value;
    })
    ->map(function ($value) {
        return $value->count();
    })
    ->all();
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method countBy does not exist @Wahyu Kristianto

Comment: Laravel version? `countBy` available from `5.8`

Comment: Laravel 6. Thank you.